# Display product custom fields in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, email-notifications

So here's the deal when i write this code in mytheme/functions.php file

```
//this code for adding field in product backend
// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields1');
// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields1()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Custom Product Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
        'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Text Field',
        'label' => __('Zoom Meeting Url ', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip' => 'true'
    ));
    //Custom Product Number Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => '_custom_product_number_field',
        'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Text Field',
        'label' => __('Meeting ID', 'woocommerce'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            // 'step' => 'any',
            // 'min' => '0'
        )
    ));
    //Custom Product  Textarea
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(array(
        'id' => '_custom_product_textarea',
        'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Text',
        'label' => __('Password', 'woocommerce')
    ));
    echo '</div>';
}
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_product_text_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_text_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));
    // Custom Product Number Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_number_field = $_POST['_custom_product_number_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_number_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field));
    // Custom Product Textarea Field
    $woocommerce_custom_procut_textarea = $_POST['_custom_product_textarea'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_procut_textarea))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_textarea', esc_html($woocommerce_custom_procut_textarea));
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wdm_add_shipping_method_to_order_email', 10, 2 );
function wdm_add_shipping_method_to_order_email( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    echo '<h4>Zoom Meeting Details</h4>';
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); //returns WC_Order if valid order 
    $items = $order->get_items();   //returns an array of WC_Order_item or a child class (i.e. WC_Order_Item_Product)
    foreach( $items as $item ) {
    $type = $item->get_type();
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    echo "<p>" . get_the_title($product_id) . "</p>";
    echo "<p><strong>Zoom Meeting Url:</strong>" . get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_product_text_field', true) . "</p>";
    echo "<p><strong>Meeting ID:</strong>" . get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_product_number_field', true) . "</p>";
    echo "<p><strong>Password:</strong>" . get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_product_textarea', true) . "</p>";


    //more code
}
}
echo get_post_meta($id, '_custom_product_text_field', true);
echo get_post_meta($id, '_custom_product_number_field', true);
echo get_post_meta($id, '_custom_product_textarea', true);
```

it works in the backend only ( product edit page )
it dose save the variables but don't show then neither in meta or before - or - after the add to card button , i couldn't find an solution for that
i tried the echo but still no results

so i thought i was my theme ? nope
i installed wordpress on other vps i have still not showing the text field-text-nothing

if you know the issue please be kind and tell me what the thing that im doing wrong!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit outdated since WooCommerce 3. Also you are using a textarea field for a password and it should be a simple text input field instead.

I have revisited your code completely:

```
// Custom function that handle your custom fields settings
function product_custom_fields_settings(){
    // Fieds Id key | Field label name (pairs)
    return array(
        'zoom_meeting_url'  => __('Meeting Url', 'woocommerce'),
        'zoom_meeting_id'   => __('Meeting Id', 'woocommerce'),
        'zoom_password'     => __('Meeting password', 'woocommerce'),
    );
}


add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'display_product_custom_fields');
function display_product_custom_fields(){
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';

    // Loop through settings Fieds Id key | Field label name (pairs)
    foreach ( product_custom_fields_settings() as $key => $label ) {
        // Input text fields
        woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
            'id' => '_'.$key,
            'label' => $label,
        ));
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_product_custom_fields');
function save_product_custom_fields( $product ){
    foreach ( product_custom_fields_settings() as $key => $label ) {
        if ( isset($_POST['_'.$key]) ) {
            $product->update_meta_data( '_'.$key, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_'.$key] ) );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'product_custom_fields_to_email_notification', 10, 4 );
function product_custom_fields_to_email_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
     // The HTML Structure
    $html_output = '<h3>'.__('Zoom meeting Details', 'woocommerce').'</h3>
    <div class="meeting-info"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6"><tbody>';

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        $html_output .= '<tr><th colspan="2">'.$item->get_name().'</th></tr>'; // Product name

        // Loop through settings Fieds Id key | Field label name (pairs)
        foreach ( product_custom_fields_settings() as $key => $label ) {
            if( $value = $product->get_meta('_'.$key) ) {
                $html_output .= '<tr><th>'.$label.':</th><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }

        // … More code …
    }

    // The CSS styling
    $styles = '<style>
    .meeting-info table{width: 100%; font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; margin-bottom:8px;}
    .meeting-info table th, table.teilnehmer-info td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px;
        color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;}
    .meeting-info table td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373;
        border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px; word-break: break-all;}
    .meeting-info table tr.subtitle h3{margin: 0;}
    </style>';

    // The Output CSS + HTML
    echo $styles . $html_output . '</tbody></table></div><br>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]